# accessing applicationStorageDirectory in Java

Tags: java, android, air

I am rewriting an application that was written in Adobe AIR - in native - Java.
there are some preferences stored in config.xml in applicationStorageDirectory that I would like to still access in the Java code.
Does anyone know how to access this file in Java?

Comment: You can use SharedPreference for storing some strings in Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AIR, `ApplicationStorageDirectory` resolves to one of these paths, depending on OS:

- **Windows 7 / Vista:** %USERPROFILE%/AppData/Roaming/*Application Name*
- **Windows XP:** %USERPROFILE%/Application Data/*Application Name*
- **Mac OS X:** ~/Library/Preferences/*Application Name*
- **Linux (Ubuntu):** ~/.appdata/*Application Name*
- **Android:** /data/data/*Application Name*